# Cannot delete table User - syntax error at or near "user" - for unknown reason

Tags: postgresql, nestjs, typeorm

For context, I am using NestJS, TypeORM and Postgres.
I'm having an issue while trying to delete my database with PostgreSQL:

```js
const repository = await this.databaseService.getRepository("User");
await repository.query(`TRUNCATE user CASCADE`);
```

This doesn't work and throws `syntax error at or near "user"`. **When using the same code with another table works perfectly**. So I assume the issue must come from my User model which looks like this:

```js
import { Exclude } from "class-transformer";
import { IsArray, IsNotEmpty, ValidateIf } from "class-validator";
import {
    Entity,
    Column,
    JoinColumn,
    OneToMany,
    PrimaryGeneratedColumn,
} from "typeorm";

import OAuthLogin from "./oAuthLogin.entity";

@Entity()
class User {
    public constructor(init?: Partial<User>) {
        Object.assign(this, init);
    }

    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    @Exclude()
    public id: number;

    @Column({ unique: true })
    public email: string;

    @Column({ unique: true })
    public username: string;

    @Column({ nullable: true })
    @Exclude()
    @IsNotEmpty()
    @ValidateIf((user) => !user.oAuthLogins || user.oAuthLogins.length === 0)
    public password?: string;

    @Column({ nullable: true })
    public imageUrl?: string;

    @Column({ nullable: true })
    public exp?: number;

    @Column({ nullable: true })
    public inviteUrl?: string;

    @JoinColumn()
    @IsArray()
    @ValidateIf((user) => !user.password)
    @OneToMany(() => OAuthLogin, (provider: OAuthLogin) => provider.user, {
        cascade: true,
        nullable: true,
    })
    public oAuthLogins: OAuthLogin[];
}

export default User;
```

Does anyone know what could prevent my table User from being deleted?

Comment: `user` is a reserved keyword you need to quote it `"User"`

Comment: Oh... I'm going to try that, thanks!

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name It seems like renaming did the trick! If you answer, I'll validate your answer